# Remove ListItem in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a ListBox in my Silverlight project.And,when to remove and add ListItem from a ListBox,I got the following error.

```
Operation not supported on read-only collection.
```

Code:

```
public void btnUp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (lbChoices.SelectedItem != null)
        {
           ListBoxItem selectedItem = new ListBoxItem();          
           selectedItem.Content = lbChoices.SelectedItem;
           selectedItem.IsSelected = true;
           int selectedIndex = lbChoices.SelectedIndex;
           if (lbChoices.Items.Count > 1)
           {              
              if (selectedIndex > 0)
                {
                    lbChoices.Items.Remove(lbChoices.SelectedItem);       
                    lbChoices.Items.Insert(selectedIndex - 1, selectedItem);                  
                  }
           }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lbChoices.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        ListBoxItem selectedItem = (ListBoxItem)lbChoices.SelectedItem; 
        int selectedIndex = lbChoices.SelectedIndex;
        if (lbChoices.Items.Count > 1)
        {
            if (selectedIndex > 0)
            {
                lbChoices.Items.Remove(lbChoices.SelectedItem);
                lbChoices.Items.Insert(selectedIndex - 1, selectedItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that your are moving up the selected item in the list box.

Comment: First of all,thanks for your interesting.Additionally,
 I want to change locations of the items with up and down button

Answer (score 1):

When you are using ItemsControl with an ItemsSource, you can not add/remove elements using the Items collection. You should modify your underlying collection instead.

"The problem stems from the fact that I’d bound my ListBox to an ObservableCollection, once bound the Items collection becomes read-only."

Answer (score 1):

I guess you added items by binding the ItemsSource? If so, remove the item from the **collection** you are binding to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the item from the source that your `ListBox` is bound to not the `ListBox` itself.  As soon as your remove it from the source, the `ListBox` will automatically refresh to not display the item.